# Adding a button to last UITableView row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm developing an app where the user can choose between a number of included songs. I also want the user to be able to choose a song from his/her iPod Library.

Currently the song is choosen by selecting it in a UITableView. So I figure I would like to add a new row at the end of the table and make it a button that will fire a MPMediaPickerController. All songs are placed in an array consisting of their names.

My question is how I add this last row? And also how I can "save" the selected song (or the path to it) to be used in the parent viewcontroller?

Comment: Why not just play the song when the user taps on its row?

Comment: I do that for the included songs. But the MediaPicker is for the user to choose a song from his/her own library. Meanwhile I managed to add a row that fires up a MediaPicker but I'm stil struggeling with checkmarks and sending the info to the parent vc which holds the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the UITableViewCell directly as a button itself, so when a user clicks on the last row, the action is being executed. But if I understand you right, you want to add a specific extra button as a subview of a UITableViewCell. That means if the cell (the last row) is being built, you compose your button, add its target and action, and add the button just as simple subview of the cell.

Well, the parent should now receive the message that the button has been pushed. I would do this using NSNotification, that is very easy to use, just check out the Apple documentation and take a look at an example. You can even send the selected song or its name path via the notification directly to the parent controller, where you can handle this notification.

Comment: I added a button to the footer and used NSNotification to message the parent. Thanks.